# Close bootstrap modal after submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How can I close the bootstrap modal after I click on the `Delete` button? Here's my code:

```
<div id="media_delete_confirmation" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
      </div>

      <form id="modal-form">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input id="media_action" value="deleteMediaAction" type="hidden"/>
          <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
          <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Keep</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal_delete">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the other part:

```
$("#modal_delete").click(function() {

  var id = $(".image-picker").val();
  var media_action = $("#media_action").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?page=myMediaController&action=deleteMedia',
    data: {'media_id' : id},
    success: function(data) {
      $("#media_delete_confirmation").modal("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you see happening? Any errors?

Comment: What happens if you move  $("#media_delete_confirmation").modal("hide"); to the start of the click event? This is not gonna fix anything, I just want to know if the modal is responding to the hide event or not regardless of the ajax call.

Comment: What you have written should work.. Check for errors in console and check for failed network requests in network tab of developer tools

Comment: There is no error in the network as well as in the console. I can't find other solution in the web. Please help me on this.

Comment: @asdasdas What is your version of Bootstrap ?

Comment: bootstrap version is 2.3.2. Anyways, data-dismiss="modal" seems to work. Thanks guys.

Comment: @asdasdas Indeed that should work

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, and was able to get the modal dialog to close this way:

```
<div id="approveDialog" class="modal approveDialog hide">
    <!-- various form elements -->
    <div class="modal-footer pull-center">
            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn">Back to Listings</a>    
            <button id="submitApprove" class="btn btn-success">Shop</button>
    </div>
</div>


$('button#submitApprove').on("click", function(event) {
    // submit form via ajax, then

    event.preventDefault();
    $('#approveDialog').modal( 'hide' );
});
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to hide model using javascript, you can simply use data-dismiss="modal" in the button tag attribute as follows.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Keep</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal_delete"  data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't submit form.(V3.)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply hide modal on submit
$('#media_delete_confirmation').modal('hide');  //to hide modal

Answer (score 0):

V3 you can try

```
 success: function(data) {
 // close modal
  $( '#media_delete_confirmation' ).modal( 'hide' ).data( 'bs.modal', null );
 // event after hidden
  $('#media_delete_confirmation').on('hidden', function(){
      $(this).data('modal', null);  // destroys modal
  });
}
```

Version 2

```
  $( '#media_delete_confirmation' ).remove();
  $( '.modal-backdrop' ).remove(); // removes the overlay
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I was trying to close a modal window after submit. The only way that I could solve it was doing the following.

In the success function, I added this code via jQuery:

```
success: function(respuesta){
    $('#btnGuardarCambios').attr("data-dismiss", "modal");
```

On the "save changes" button, I used the `attr` method. If the ajax is successful, I just add a new attribute (`data-dismiss`) and set the value of it (modal) else the modal won't disappear.

EDIT: This isn´t working on IE and Chrome, only works on Mozilla :c

Answer (score 0):

Just try on a `<script>` before the end of your body writing this

```
$('#media_delete_confirmation').submit(function() {
        $('#media_delete_confirmation').modal('hide');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

first add a id or class in this submit button like closemodel. then add another id 
or class in this first div. then add this jquery code

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#closemodel').click(function() {
    $('#CreateAccount1').modal('toggle');
  });
});
</script>
```