# close boostrap modal when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked at some examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754902/close-bootstrap-modal-after-submit) , but answer there is to put  `data-dismiss="modal"` on the submit button. However, it does not process the form. It just closes the modal.

How can we close it once the form is submitted?

here is my modal form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <form  role="form" id="contact-form" method="post">      
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Your name:</label>
            <input name="name" required="" type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name"/>
          </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit now</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one working for me

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function() {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to dismiss the form modal, upon submission, is through `xhr` or have a Javascript callback to trigger the dismissal.

You need the [Bootstrap javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) loaded in order to make these calls, but there are many examples on the documentation page linked. For your specific example, try running this in the Dev tools console of your browser when you have the modal up:

```
$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
```